# undefined method for new specified column

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I had to create a new migration to add "feet" and "inches" to the profile page so that users can enter their height. I ran the command:

> rails generate migration AddFeetAndInchesToUsers feet:integer
>   inches:integer

thinking that would get it to work and it didn't. I am receiving the error message 
`

> "undefined method `feet' for #User:0x007fe41dbe9520"

` when trying to view profile page.

I have all the other fields working for my profile page as I have defined them in the user model previously by doing "rails g resource user then-all-my-options-here". But now I need to define feet, inches, religion and religion importance. I'm not understanding how to add to an existing model.

I have added those values to the create_profiles.rb which is in the db folder. Added to profile.rb and user.rb. None of those work. I believe to fix it I need to somehow get it inside user.rb the proper way, as I only typed it into the  attr_accessible and I'm sure to properly get "feet, options, and religion options" to work is to go through the terminal first.

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :about_me, :feet, :inches, :password, :birthday, :career, :children, :education, :email, :ethnicity, :gender, :height, :name, :password_digest, :politics, :religion, :sexuality, :user_drink, :user_smoke, :username, :zip_code
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create
  before_create { generate_token(:auth_token) }

  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    UserMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
  end
end
```

show.html.erb (profile page):

```
<h1><%= @user.username %></h1>

<h2>Basics</h2>

<%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :height %><br/>
        <%= f.select :feet, [['Feet', nil], '4', '5', '6'] %>
        <%= f.select :inches, [['Inches', nil], '0', '1', '2', '3', '4',                    
                                '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11'] %>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :children %><br/>
        <%= f.select :children, [['Do you have or want kids?', nil], 'Yes, they live with me', 'I want kids now', 'I want one someday', 'Not for me']%>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :religion %><br/>
        <%= f.select :religion, [['What is your faith?', nil], 'Agnostic', 'Atheist', 'Christian', 'Catholic', 'Buddhist', 'Hindu', 'Jewish', 'Muslim', 'Spiritual without affiliation', 'Other', 'None', 'Prefer not to say'  ]%><br/>
        <%= f.select :religion, [['How important is this to you?', nil], 'Very Important', 'Somewhat Important', 'Not Important']%>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :career %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :career %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :education %><br/>
        <%= f.select :education, [['What is your education level?', nil], 'High school', 'Some college', 'Undergraduate', "Bachelor's", "Master's ", 'PhD', 'Business school', 'Law school', 'Medical school' ]%>
        </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :ethnicity %><br/>
        <%= f.select :ethnicity, [['What is your ethnicity?', nil], 'Asian', 'Black', 'Biracial', 'Indian', 'Hispanic/Latin', 'Middle Eastern', 'Native American', 'Pacific Islander', 'White', 'Other' ]%>
        </div>
        <%= f.label :user_drink %><br/>
        <%= f.select :user_drink, [['How much do you drink?', nil], 'Often Drinks', 'Sometimes drinks', 'Never drinks', 'No comment' ]%>
        </div><br/>
        <%= f.label :user_smoke %><br/>
        <%= f.select :user_smoke, [['How often do you smoke?', nil], 'Often smokes', 'Sometimes smokes', 'Never smokes'] %>
        </div>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>

    <h3>About Me</h3>

    <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :about_me %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :about_me %>
    <div class="actions"><%= f.submit %></div>

<% end %>
<% end %>
```

add_feet_and_inches_to_users.rb (this is in /db folder and was created after I ran the command posted on top of post):

```
class AddFeetAndInchesToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :feet, :integer
    add_column :users, :inches, :integer
  end
end
```

Comment: Obvious steps first: did you run rake db:migrate?

Comment: Yes. Rake aborted. As for some reason when I entered that command, after attempting to migrate it also showed "-- add_column(:users, :password_digest, :string)". Which of course has already been created. So I received this in following "Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'password_digest': ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `password_digest` varchar(255)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed the proper steps originally. What held me up is the error I received from trying to run rake db:migrate. I had duplicate columns. So to find the duplicate I ran "grep password_digest db/migrate/*". That in return showed me the files with the duplicate content, I deleted them and now my fields work.